# SQL Soma por períodos

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou com uma dúvida para montar uma query, seguinte:

Em minha tabela de vendas gostaria de retornar a soma por período de determinado produto. Hoje estou fazendo desta forma:

```
select YEAR(venda.data_venda) as Ano,
venda.codprod_venda as CodigoProduto,
produtos.descricao_prod,
MONTH(venda.data_venda) as Mes,
SUM(venda.qntdporprod_venda) as QtdVendida

FROM venda, produtos WHERE venda.codprod_venda = produtos.codigo_prod and produtos.codigo_prod=1
GROUP BY YEAR(data_venda), cod_prod_venda, MONTH(data_venda)
ORDER BY YEAR(data_venda), cod_prod_venda, MONTH(data_venda)
```

Este select retorna a soma de determinado produto por mês e não por período.
Porém no meu caso, preciso fazer a soma no período de 30 dias, por exemplo 05.09.2015 e a busca fosse feita do dia 04.09.2015 até 03.10.2015 e depois 04.10.2015 até 03.11.2015 e assim por diante. Não sei se é possível realizar este select, gostaria de uma opinião.

Obrigada!

Comment: Prefira colocar o código como texto aqui, fica mais fácil para as pessoas ajudarem. Se quiser facilitar mesmo e aumentar suas chances de obter uma resposta crie um http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ com a estrutura e dados para as pessoas testarem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente incluindo este comando na sua cláusula where:

```
V.data >= '01/09/2015' and V.data <= DATEADD(DAY,30, '01/09/2015')
```

Sua query ficaria assim, fiz uma melhoria utilizando INNER JOIN também:

```
select YEAR(V.data_venda) as Ano,
V.codprod_venda as CodigoProduto,
P.descricao_prod,
MONTH(V.data_venda) as Mes,
SUM(V.qntdporprod_venda) as QtdVendida

FROM venda V join produtos P 
on V.codprod_venda = P.codigo_prod
WHERE  P.codigo_prod = 1 and

       V.data >= '01/09/2015' and V.data <= DATEADD(DAY,30, '01/09/2015')

GROUP BY YEAR(V.data_venda), cod_prod_venda, MONTH(V.data_venda)
ORDER BY YEAR(V.data_venda), cod_prod_venda, MONTH(V.data_venda)
```

Espero que isso resolva, caso ainda necessite da ajuda, crie um [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) como exemplo para podermos ajudar melhor.

Comment: Muito Obrigada, deu certinho..!!!!!